# Turning a Netgear Router into a Wired Bridge

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, home-networking

I currently have my wireless network setup through a TP-Link AC1900 router. I also have a Netgear WNDR4000 router that currently isn't being used.

**My current home network setup is as follows:**

*Modem is connected to the TP-Link router which has a couple connections wired to it as well as being connected to an 8 port switch that is connected to various ethernet wall ports in my house.*

What I'd like to do is turn my Netgear router into a bridge (or is it repeater?) which I would **plug into** one of my Ethernet wall ports in a different location of the house and then have it repeat the same network at full strength from that location.

My question is, first, is this even possible having 2 different company routers? and second, if it is, how would I go about setting up the Netgear router to achieve the result I'm looking for?

I've tried numerous times from various google search results but nothing has really helped/worked.

*I'm on a Mac if that matters at all*

Comment: Do you want an Ethernet-to-Ethernet bridge, or an Ethernet-to-WiFi one?

Comment: Both routers will be plugged in with ethernet wire.

Comment: For a wireless repeater (instead of a wireless access point) see pages 83-86 of the [***WNDR4000 User Manual***](http://documentation.netgear.com/wndr4000/enu/202-10781-01/usermanual.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking the Netgear to do is to become an access point. Just transmit the same network name as your current network on the TP-LINK. Luckily, the netgear has an Access Point mode.

The instructions to enable access point mode are here
http://bit.ly/netgearaccesspoint

If you follow those instructions and enable the dhcp client on the access point, as long as you change the SSID (transmitted name) and WPA/WPA2 settings from the TP-LINK you should be good to go.

You are getting all your terminology wrong and could be very confusing - Please make sure you understand what a bridge/repeater is and does - If you have been searching with those terms you will not find any relevant information.

Comment: "Bridge" is a fine term for both a switch and an AP, though probably too generic. Some home routers actually call the same mode "bridge mode".

Comment: @JohnnyVegas So if I change the the settings on my Netgear router to the same as the TP-Link one and then enable the AP Mode in the settings, that's all I'll need to do? I won't have to change anything on the the TP-Link router (Like enable WDS Bridging?).

Comment: Please *read* the instructions fully that I linked to. Nothing needs to be changed on the TP-LINK.

Comment: I did, however, after reading the instructions, my Netgear router is still showing both it's own 2.4 and 5 GHz SSID's when I look up wifi networks instead of my TP-Link SSID name. From above where you say"Just transmit the same network name as your current network..." do you mean to make the Netgear SSID the same as my TP-Link one and same password and then follow the instructions at the link?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Your suggestions worked. I did change the SSID and password to the same as my current router and then followed the AP info at the link supplied and everything seems to be in order now. Thanks again!
The only thing I wasn't sure about was the Device Name under the AP Settings so I just named it the same as the SSID.

Answer (score 0):

The router *already* acts as a bridge:

- Internally, the four "LAN" ports all belong to the same Ethernet switch and traffic between them is not routed. (It probably doesn't even reach the OS.)
- The built-in Wi-Fi access point is also bridged (usually at OS level) to the built-in "LAN" switch.

The Netgear website has documentation on [configuring the device for "AP mode"](https://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20927?cid=wmt_netgear_organic), which disables all routing features and leaves only the Ethernet switch & Wi-Fi AP.

If that doesn't work, the alternative method would be to simply turn off DHCP and UPnP, and connect everything to "LAN" ports only.